# Docker container on host with two NICs connected to internet

Tags: linux, docker, routes, iptables

I'm running a docker container with port 6882 exposed on a host with two NICs. Each NIC is connected to a router with a public IP address.

How can I allow my docker to be reached through both public IPs? Currently it only works with one public IP where the default gateway is connected to.

*Update the docker command:

```
$ docker run <image_name> -p 6882:6882 ...
```

Basically I bind the 6882 to all interfaces.

Actually for the second public IP address, if I'm in the network of the second router I can still reach the container through the second public IP. But if I'm outside, the default gateway doesn't allow the container to return the packets through the second interface.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything; the default behavior of `docker run -p` is to bind to all host interfaces.  Can you include your `docker run` command in the question?

Comment: I updated the docker command. The docker can be reached if I'm within the network of the second router but not if I'm outside.